# Rails 5 - NoMethod Error - undefined method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

In the app I am building to learn Rails, I have a polymorphic relationship between the model "TAG" and the models "ANNOTATION" and "DOCUMENT". Similar to Article and Comment models.

Create and destroy of tags is working. Now, I want to update the tags and run into a no method error I don't understand. Tried many alternatives (e.g. using `<%= link_to tag.content, [object, tag]...` with the form `<%= simple_form_for object.tag ...` ).

The form is called using:

```
<% object.tags.each do |tag| %>
        <% unless tag.content.blank? %>
        <tr>
            <td><%= link_to tag.content, @tag, method: :patch %></td>
```

This is the tags controller:

```
class TagsController < ApplicationController

def index

end

def create
  tagable = detect_tagable
  tagable.tags.create(tag_params)
  redirect_to tagable_path(tagable)
end

def update
  tagable = detect_tagable
  @tag = tagable.tags.find(params[:id]) 
  @tag.save
  render '_tag_update'
end

def destroy
  tagable = detect_tagable
  @tag = tagable.tags.find(params[:id])
  @tag.destroy
  redirect_to tagable_path(tagable)
end

private

  def tagable_path(tagable)
    case tagable
    when Document
      document_path(tagable)
    when Annotation
      annotate_path(tagable)
    else
      fail 'Unknown tagable'
    end
  end

  def detect_tagable
    if params[:annotation_id]
      Annotation.find(params[:annotation_id])
    elsif params[:document_id]
      Document.find(params[:document_id])
    else
      fail 'Tagable not found'
    end
  end

  def tag_params
    params.require(:tag).permit(:content, :location, :tagtype_id,annotation_attributes: { annotation_ids:[] }, document_attributes: { document_ids:[] })
  end

end
```

It renders the correct form `_tag_update.html.erb` with the right parameters (annotation id and tag id) yet throws the error on:

```
<%= simple_form_for @tag, html: { class: 'form-vertical', multipart: true },
```

**Full error**

> NoMethodError in Tags#update
>   Showing /Users/Dimitri/Documents/AppDev/shine/app/views/tags/_tag_update.html.erb where line #1 raised:
>   undefined method `tag_path' for #<#:0x007fc2aede9d88>
>   Did you mean?  tagtype_path
>   Extracted source (around line #1):
>   1
>   2
>   3
>   4
>   5
>   6
>   <%= simple_form_for @tag, html: { class: 'form-vertical', multipart: true },
>       wrapper: :horizontal_form,
>       wrapper_mappings: {
>       check_boxes: :horizontal_radio_and_checkboxes,
>       radio_buttons: :horizontal_radio_and_checkboxes,
>       file: :horizontal_file_input,
>   Rails.root: /Users/Dimitri/Documents/AppDev/shine

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace:

> app/views/tags/_tag_update.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_tags__tag_update_html_erb___1949489846228898836_70237067101380'
>   app/controllers/tags_controller.rb:17:in`update'
>   Request

Parameters:

`{"_method"=>"patch", "authenticity_token"=>"LhqKjyjbYdznMvx+GjsIL0phwT8pRTtanooKU6Xt4hHaPRFMmZJmZVm7GGZa8iaWxN1MIfm7xHwwhSSrSBoO/g==", "annotation_id"=>"6", "id"=>"24"}`

Comment: please post the full error log

Comment: hi Deepak, done

Comment: `<%= link_to tag.content, @tag, method: :patch %>` @tag? or tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you pass a record to `link_to`, `form_for` or `redirect_to` rails passes the record to the [polymorphic route helpers](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/PolymorphicRoutes.html) (note that this has nothing to do with polymorphic associations).

To generate a route to a nested resource you need to pass both the parent and child record:

```
simple_form_for( [@tag.taggable, @tag],  # ...

link_to( @tag.content, [@tag.taggable, @tag] )

redirect_to( [@tag.taggable, @tag] )
```

From your controller you don't need to do:

```
def tagable_path(tagable)
  case tagable
  when Document
    document_path(tagable)
  when Annotation
    annotate_path(tagable)
  else
    fail 'Unknown tagable'
  end
end
```

Just `redirect_to taggable` and rails will figure out the route for you by using the clever conventions.

### Nesting is not always good.

Member routes do not need to be nested. Since each record be accessed by a unique id you can unnest the member routes:

```
# avoids duplication
concern :taggable do
  resources :tags, only: [:new, :index, :create]
end

# generates GET|PATCH|DELETE /tags/:id and /tags/:id/edit
resources :tags, only: [:show, :edit, :destroy, :update]

resources :documents, concerns: :taggable
resources :annotations, concerns: :taggable
```

The `resources :annotations, shallow: true` option gives somewhat similar results.

This means that you can do `redirect_to(@tag)` or `link_to('Delete tag', @tag, method: :delete )`

Comment: And for render? How to pass the object?

Comment: When you are passing locals with render that just like straight up argument passing - wether or not the routes are nested is irrelevant.

Comment: So in case like this render ... , @tag.tagable

Comment: You can do it like `render partial: 'foo', tag: @tag` or `render partial: 'foo', tag: @tag, taggable: @tag.taggable`. The same applies to controller instance variables. Its really up to you.

Comment: If you really need your views and partials to be able to shortcut to to `taggable` then pass it as a local. Otherwise its perfectly fine to do `tag.taggable` in a partial such as a form.

Comment: am lost. If in my controller I replace 'redirect_to tagable_path(tagable)' - with ... 'redirect_to tagable_path(tagable)' I get an error: undefined method `tagable' for nil:NilClass; same error for the link_to...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125789/discussion-between-max-and-dimitri-de-ruiter).

Comment: any time you got time, max