# Rails - render a view in a view - pass params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb, ruby-on-rails-5

In my app, I can call a view ('edit.html.erb') using:

```
<%= link_to( tag.content, [object, tag], method: :patch) %>
```

What would be the equivalent if I would want to render it within an other view ?

How would I pass it the params?

**Edit**

In effect I have a view of the parent, in which I want to list the children (editable). These I could edit separately too. Simple solution is that I, create a _partial which I render from the parent's view as well as from `edit.html.erb`.

I can call this `edit.html.erb` (or update) using the link:

```
<%= link_to( tag.content, [object, tag], method: :patch) %>
```

This works. Now question is how to render that partial (let's call it `_update.html.erb`) using render? Still need to pass the parent (i.e. object) and child (tag) params. How do I do that using `<% render partial "tags/update" PARAMS %>`?

### **Edit for full example**

What I am trying to achieve (in short) - allow editing of tags (child) in annotate view (parent).

For an existing record of model/ object "Annotation", I want to add tags for an attached PDF. I do this in a page/view named "Annotate", that I open from the Annotation edit view (using 'link_to'). This "Annotate" page has 2 columns (see screenshot below):

1. left pane: 2 sections - 1 to quickly add the tag(s) and - 2 to edit existing tags (listed in a table)
2. right pane: the PDF

[image]

Tags and Annotation have polymorphic relationship (set up as per this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40058119/4201809))

`_form.html.erb` *for Annotation*

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
  <%= simple_form_for @annotation,  html: { class: 'form-horizontal', multipart: true },
    wrapper: :horizontal_form,
    wrapper_mappings: {
        check_boxes: :horizontal_radio_and_checkboxes,
        radio_buttons: :horizontal_radio_and_checkboxes,
        file: :horizontal_file_input,
        boolean: :horizontal_boolean
    } do |f| %>

    <div class="btn-toolbar btn-group", role="toolbar">
      <%= f.button :submit, 'Save', :class => "btn btn-xs btn-default" %> <%= link_to 'List' , annotations_path, :class => "btn btn-xs btn-default" %> <% unless @annotation.file.blank? %>
    <%= link_to 'Annotate', annotate_path(@annotation), :class => "btn btn-xs btn-default" %>
    <% end -%>
    </div>

    <h4>Annotation</h4>

    <%= f.error_notification %>

    <% if @annotation.file.blank? %>
      <%= f.input :file, as: :file, input_html: { accept: ('application/pdf') } %>
      <% else %>
    <% end -%>

    <%= f.input :name, placeholder: 'Enter name' %>

    <%= f.input :description, placeholder: 'Description', :input_html => { :rows => 3 } %>

    <%= f.association :documenttype, :collection => Documenttype.active.order(:name), prompt: 'Select document type' %>

    <%= f.association :sender, label: 'Submitted by' , prompt: 'Select sender' %>

    <%= f.association :receiver, label: 'Specific to', prompt: 'Select recipient' %>

    <%= f.input :active, as: :boolean %>

<% end -%>
  </div>

    <% unless @annotation.file.blank? %>
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <%= content_tag :iframe, nil, src: pdf_annotation_path(@annotation), width: "100%", height: "770px", frameBorder: "0" %>
        </div>
      <% end %>
    </div>
    <% unless @annotation.new_record? %>
      <div class="row">
        <hr>
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <%= render @annotation.comments %>
          </div>

          <div class="col-md-6">
            <%= render 'comments/form', :object => @annotation %>
          </div>
      </div>
    <% end -%>
```

*Annotate view* `annotate.html.erb`

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-5">
        <div class="btn-toolbar btn-group" role="toolbar">
            <%= link_to 'Close', annotation_path(@annotation), :class => "btn btn-xs btn-default" %> <%= link_to 'List' , annotations_path, :class => "btn btn-xs btn-default" %>
        </div>
        <h4>Annotate document</h4>
        <div data-spy="affix">
                <%= render 'tags/form', :object => @annotation %>
                <br>
            <div class="panel panel-default" id="annotationResults">
                <%= render 'tags/tag_list', :object => @annotation %>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-7" id="file">
        <%= content_tag :iframe, nil, src: pdf_annotation_path(@annotation), width: "100%", height: "875px", frameBorder: "0" %>
    </div>

</div>
```

*tag list* `_tag_list.html.erb`

```
<table id="tags" class="table table-hover" style="background-color: white; word-wrap: break-word; font-size: 0.9em;" >
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Tagged content</th>
            <th>as</th>
            <th>in</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <% object.tags.each do |tag| %>
            <% unless tag.content.blank? %>
            <tr data-tag-id='<%= tag.id %>', class='show-tag'>
                <td style="word-wrap: break-word;"><%= link_to( tag.content, [object, tag], method: :patch) %>
                <td><%= tag.tagtype.name %></td>
                <td><%= tag.tagtype.typeoftag %></td>
                <td><%= link_to '', [object, tag], method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Please confirm!' }, :class => "glyphicon glyphicon-trash" %></td>
            </tr>
            <tr data-tag-id='<%= tag.id %>', class='edit-tag'>
                <td colspan="4"><%= render partial: 'shared/tester' %><%#= render partial: 'tags/update', object: @tag.tagable, tag: @tag %></td>
            </tr>
            <% end -%>
        <% end -%>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

*tag update form* `_update.html.erb`

```
<%= simple_form_for [object, tag], html: { class: 'form-horizontal', multipart: true },
    wrapper: :horizontal_form,
    wrapper_mappings: {
        check_boxes: :horizontal_radio_and_checkboxes,
        radio_buttons: :horizontal_radio_and_checkboxes,
        boolean: :horizontal_boolean
      } do |f| %>

  <div class="btn-toolbar btn-group" role="toolbar">
    <%= f.button :submit, 'Save', :class => "btn btn-xs btn-default" %>
  </div>

    <%= f.error_notification %>

  tag id = <%= @tag.id %>

    <%= f.input :content, placeholder: 'Tagged content'%>

    <%= f.association :tagtype, prompt: 'Select tag type', :collection => Tagtype.active.order(:name).where(:documenttype => @tag.tagable.documenttype_id) %>

    <%= f.input :location, prompt: 'add as: x1, y1, x2, y2' %>

<% end -%>
```

Routes

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root 'dashboard#index'
  devise_for :users

  concern :tagable do
    resources :tags, only: [:new, :index, :create, :edit, :update]
  end

  resources :users, :documenttypes, :tagtypes, :business_partners
  resources :tags, only: [:show, :edit, :destroy, :index]

  resources :documents do
    resources :comments
    resources :tags, concerns: :tagable
    get "pdf", on: :member 
  end

  resources :annotations do
    resources :comments
    resources :tags
    get "pdf", on: :member

end

get "annotations/:id/annotate" => "annotations#annotate", as: 'annotate'
```

*Tags controller*

```
class TagsController < ApplicationController

    def index
    @tags = Tag.all.order(:tagable)
    end

  def show
    tagable = detect_tagable
    @tag = tagable.tags.find(params[:id])
  end

  def edit
    tagable = detect_tagable
    @tag = tagable.tags.find(params[:id])
    @tag.update(tag_params)
  end

  def create
    tagable = detect_tagable
    tagable.tags.create(tag_params)
    redirect_to tagable_path(tagable)
  end

  def update
    tagable = detect_tagable
    @tag = tagable.tags.find(params[:id])
    render 'edit'
#    @tag.save
    @tag.update(tag_params)
  end

  def destroy
    tagable = detect_tagable
    @tag = tagable.tags.find(params[:id])
    @tag.destroy
    redirect_to tagable_path(tagable)
  end

  private

    def tagable_path(tagable)
      case tagable
      when Document
        document_path(tagable)
      when Annotation
        annotate_path(tagable)
      else
        fail 'Unknown tagable'
      end
    end

    def detect_tagable
      if params[:annotation_id]
        Annotation.find(params[:annotation_id])
      elsif params[:document_id]
        Document.find(params[:document_id])
      else
        fail 'Tagable not found'
      end
    end

    def tag_params
      params.require(:tag).permit(:content, :location, :tagtype_id, annotation_attributes: { annotation_ids:[] }, document_attributes: { document_ids:[] })
    end

end
```

This is what I have made - if there is a better way in Rails (which I can image) more then willing to learn.

Comment: You can't "call views", all you can do is route to actions. You're thinking about this backwards.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand you completely but are you trying to have this link appear in another view, perhaps in a partial?

Comment: agreed. a little more detail. The question you should ask yourself is whether or not the data for the second view is available in the first view (the controller context when rendering that first view). If it is, or you can make it be, then a partial is what you want--and passing values into a partial is supported and straightforward

Comment: added more detail. Any comment, critique etc welcome!

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#passing-local-variables

Comment: @max, thanks for pointing to the specific section, have studied. Now, still don't get it. I need to pass multiple variables for the form <%= simple_form_for [@tag.tagable, @tag], ... Just don't see how.

Comment: `<% render partial "tags/update" foo: 'bar', baz: 2 %>` but I think you should really start with something like railstutorial since you seem to be lacking in the basic aspects of how rails apps are built.

Comment: @max - I agree; I do not fully understand the concepts yet. tutorial - that's what I take often; like I followed rails getting started, read the guides. Now, I have not seen the sample that I have - which one covers this please? tx.

Comment: https://www.railstutorial.org/ otherwise read the rails guides on rendering. But I think you are just not getting the general concept of MVC - you don't render a update view - you use `button_to` or a form and so that the user sends a new request. Passing local variables to a partial is just like passing arguments to a function - I don't really see why you're not getting it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125988/discussion-between-dimitri-de-ruiter-and-max).

Comment: @max - I got that. No issue. Also, I have switch to rendering a form (in a partial called _update.html.erb). If I now pass 2 variables `object: @tag.tagable, tag: @tag` I get the error "undefined method 'tagable' for nil:NilClass."

Comment: If you edit the question to contain a full example with the relevant code and a desired result than I can help you.

Comment: @max - edited with explanation, screenshot et al. will add the tags controller

Comment: @max - any chance you can help me here? Tried almost anything I can find on rendering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach taken here should be to use nested forms, `accepts_nested_attributes_for` with `allow_destroy: true` and `reject_if` for the validations.

- to destroy nested records, use `accepts_nested_attributes_for :tags, allow_destroy: true` and ensure that (besides :id) also `:_destroy`
  is added to strongparams
- to use validations for nested fields, use
  `accepts_nested_attributes_for :tags, allow_destroy: true,
  reject_if: :something_to_check`